# Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) in Scikit-Learn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-analysis

i get the GMM models of generation of electricity for my SPS (solar power station) through scikit-learn and search Probability Density Function (PDF, black line):

[image: fig.1]

But i want get a probability function (CDF or Cumulative distribution function). In other words, i want to get a function like an example:

[image: fig.2]

that can receive values on axes y in range [0, 1] and grows on all x-axis. Does scikit-learn allow it or not?

Comment: don't get your question , do you need probability or density?

Comment: i need "cumulative probability function" (CDF) (sry, forgot that definition earlier when asked a question) instead "probability density function" (PDF) (it is two different functions with different meanings as I know)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's say you have done something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture

# create data
rng = np.random.RandomState(seed=42)
X = np.concatenate([rng.normal(0, 1, 100),
                    rng.normal(10, 3, 100),
                    rng.normal(30, 2, 100)]).reshape(-1, 1)

# estimate probability density function (pdf) 
model = GaussianMixture(n_components=2)
model.fit(X) 
x = np.linspace(-10, 40, 1000)
logprob = model.score_samples(x.reshape(-1, 1))
pdf = np.exp(logprob)
```

Then you can get the cumulative distribution function by simply taking the cumulative sum over the estimated density values, and scaling it so that the maximum value is 1:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# derive cumulative distribution function (cdf)
cdf = np.cumsum(pdf)
# scale as a probability distribution
cdf = cdf / np.max(cdf)

# plot data and pdf  
plt.hist(X, 25, density=True, histtype='stepfilled', alpha=0.3)
plt.plot(x, pdf, '-k')

# plot cdf, scaled to the y limits of the above plot
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = plt.axis()
plt.plot(x, cdf * ymax, '-b');
```

[image: Plot of the data, pdf, and cdf]

Comment: reallly works) thx for you)